# VBA MACRO Combobox is limited in data

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have a script in VBA (downloaded from internet and adjusted to my use). It is for Data Entry. But i have the problem with some Comboboxes. It is not alowing me to see the whole list of choises. It only shows 2 values instead of the 128 values.

I have tried to put it in a different column but still the same. At this moment ***C_06.List = [bom].Value*** is my problem!

```
   Option Explicit
Dim Rng As Range, fnd As Range
Dim Ctrl As Control
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim wsAE As Worksheet
Private Sub C_02_Click()
T_ARR.Value = C_02.Column(1)
T_RENOV.Value = C_02.Column(3)
T_FINC.Value = C_02.Column(4)
T_AREA.Value = C_02.Column(9)
T_CALLE.Value = C_02.Column(11)
T_DIAS.Value = C_02.Column(12)
T_ESTATUS.Value = C_02.Column(13)
T_SUELO.Value = C_02.Column(15)
T_COLONIA.Value = C_02.Column(16)
T_CP.Value = C_02.Column(14)
T_ESTADO.Value = C_02.Column(17)
T_M2.Value = C_02.Column(20)
End Sub


Private Sub CMB_addnew_Click()
Set wsAE = Worksheets("INGRESOS")
If MsgBox("Correct entry?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Check the data!") = vbNo Then Exit Sub
iRow = wsAE.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1
wsAE.Cells(iRow, 1).Resize(, 25).Value = Array(T_id.Value, C_02.Value, T_AREA.Value, T_ARR.Value, T_DATE.Value, C_CONC.Value, T_REFBANC.Value, T_PROYECTO.Value, T_CARGO.Value, T_RAD.Value, T_NRAD.Value, T_NPAGO.Value, C_METH.Value, T_RENOV.Value, T_FINC.Value, _
 T_DIAS.Value, T_PAGARFEC.Value, T_SUELO.Value, T_ESTATUS.Value, T_M2.Value, T_CALLE.Value, T_COLONIA.Value, T_ESTADO.Value, T_CP.Value, _
 , T_NOTA.Value)
'Columns.AutoFit
MsgBox "The new entry has been saved.", vbInformation, "Done"
For Each Ctrl In Controls
    If TypeName(Ctrl) = "TextBox" Or TypeName(Ctrl) = "ComboBox" Then Ctrl.Value = ""
Next Ctrl
LB_01.ListIndex = -1
LB_01.TopIndex = 0
Call UserForm_Initialize
End Sub

Private Sub CMB_clear_Click()
For Each Ctrl In Controls
    If TypeName(Ctrl) = "TextBox" Or TypeName(Ctrl) = "ComboBox" Then Ctrl.Value = ""
Next Ctrl
LB_01.ListIndex = -1
LB_01.TopIndex = 0
Call UserForm_Initialize
End Sub
Private Sub CMB_close_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub
Private Sub LB_01_Click()
T_id.Value = LB_01.Column(0)
C_02.Value = LB_01.Column(1)
T_ARR.Value = LB_01.Column(2)
T_CARGO.Value = LB_01.Column(3)
T_RENOV.Value = LB_01.Column(4)
T_FINC.Value = LB_01.Column(5)
C_METH.Value = LB_01.Column(6)
C_EMPTY.Value = LB_01.Column(7)
C_CONC.Value = LB_01.Column(8)
T_NRAD.Value = LB_01.Column(9)
T_NOTA.Value = LB_01.Column(10)
T_DIAS.Value = LB_01.Column(11)
T_PAGARFEC.Value = LB_01.Column(12)
T_NPAGO.Value = LB_01.Column(13)
C_06.Value = LB_01.Column(14)
C_BOM.Value = LB_01.Column(15)
T_CP.Value = LB_01.Column(16)
T_ESTADO.Value = LB_01.Column(17)
T_DATE.Value = LB_01.Column(18)
T_PROYECTO.Value = LB_01.Column(19)
T_RAD.Value = LB_01.Column(20)
T_AREA.Value = LB_01.Column(21)
T_CALLE.Value = LB_01.Column(22)
T_ESTATUS.Value = LB_01.Column(23)
T_SUELO.Value = LB_01.Column(24)
T_COLONIA.Value = LB_01.Column(25)
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
T_id.Value = WorksheetFunction.Max([ids]) + 1
LB_01.List = [database].Value
C_02.List = [datalist].Value
C_CONC.List = [nouns].Value
C_BOM.List = [mrp].Value
C_METH.List = [BUoM].Value
C_06.List = [bom].Value
T_DATE.Value = Now
End Sub
```

Comment: Where this `C_06` is loaded? In which combo there are 128 values and you can see only 2? Are those value loaded in combo and just not shown, or they are not loaded?

Comment: C_06 is loaded like all other Comboboxes (worksheet called Lists) and in there the column BOM is where all 128 values are. But i only get to see 2 (the first two to be exact)

Comment: Try to be more specific on what the issue is, and where the code is spedifically breaking!

Comment: If you try `Debug.Print [bom].Rows.count` what does this line return in Immediate Window?

Comment: I get a error in return Run-time error 13 Type mismatch

Comment: So, `bom` is a named range, right?  What range does it refer to?

Comment: Please go in your Excel sheet and click in the Name box (left side of the formula bar) and write "bom" (without double quotes). Press Enter after that. What range is selected? When you try to replay of one of my comments, please use @DaneDuru. Otherwise, I do not know that you made a reply. You received our reply only due to the fact that you placed the question...

Comment: Or go to Formulas -> Name Manager and see what range [bom] Refers To...

Comment: @FaneDuru that was exactly the problem the name manager